# Handle mouse events in QListView

Tags: qt, qt4, qt5, qt4.8

I've `Dialog` that shows folders (in `treeView`) and **files** (in `listView`) respectively. In **listView** `doubleClick` signal is handled by a slot that Qt created while I used Designer with aproppriate slot to be implemented. The problem is that I'm not able to handle `RIGHT MOUSE` **click**. Is there a solution?

P.S. 
I've googled for a while to solve this problem, it seems that inheriting QListView and overriding solve the problem. But in my case I've already populated Qt's standart `QListView` using Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use event filter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{

    if (obj == ui->listView->viewport() && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
    {
        QMouseEvent *ev = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
        if (ev->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)
        {
            qDebug()<< "double clicked" << ev->pos();
            qDebug()<<  ui->listView->indexAt(ev->pos()).data();
        }
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

To use `eventFilter` you should also:

```
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);//in header
```

and

```
qApp->installEventFilter(this);//in constructor
```

Possible addition to your problem. If you want do different things when user clicks left or right mouse buttons you should handle lest and right clicks in filter, without doubleClick signal (because it emits signal in both cases) and your code can be something like:

```
QMouseEvent *ev = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>(event);
if (ev->buttons() & Qt::RightButton)
{
    qDebug()<< "RightButton double clicked";
    //do something
}
if (ev->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
{
    qDebug()<< "LeftButton double clicked";
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! Does this work in Dialog because I've creted project with `QDialog`? Sorry for trivial question?

Comment: @elgolondrino Yes, just write Dialog instead of MAinWindow, but why you can't use just doubleClicked signal? do you want different reaction when user clicks right or left mouse buttons? `void MainWindow::on_listView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index){qDebug() << index.data();}`

Comment: Because I've already used that slot in order to open files in `listView` and didn't want to open files in `right-double click` but instead solely in **left** one! :)

Comment: A question could you tell why am I suppose to return `QObject::eventFilter(obj, event)` in overridden method?

Comment: @elgolondrino The best answer there is in doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters

Comment: So you do advice NOT to use `on_listView_doubleClicked` slot but instead override *eventFilter*? Sorry :) If yes, how can I handle signal emitted?

Comment: @elgolondrino Yes, because doubleClicked works with left and right buttons. How can you find which button was pressed? Do all what you need inside filter or create your own signal which you can emit from filter and handle in some custom slot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66410/discussion-between-elgolondrino-and-chernobyl).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I started trying to catch mouse events when a user right-clicked on a line in the QListView, but they never came through.  However, all I really wanted to do was popup a context menu, and it turns out the contextMenuEvent did get through!  So I didn't have to subclass QListView, just added a contextMenuEvent() to my widget that contained the QListView.

This was Qt3, so your mileage will most definitely differ.